# How to clone only a specific number of elements?

Tags: jquery, clone

i got 10+ img divs like `<img class="thumbnail22">`.

But i want to clone only the first 5 elements (img divs).

With `$('img.thumbnail22').clone().prependTo(".cloned");`i clone them into the .cloned div, which works.
But how can i clone only the first 5 elements?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to limit the number of elements you want to keep from your selector.

```
$('img.thumbnail22').slice(0, 5).clone().prependTo(".cloned");
```

The other way is to limit the number of elements directly in the selector using [:lt()](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
$('img.thumbnail22:lt(5)').clone().prependTo(".cloned");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `slice()`ing it

```
$('img.thumbnail22').slice(0,20).clone().prependTo(".cloned");
```

Remember, jQuery objects are extensions of an array.